# which encryption is used in this JS Variables

Tags: encryption, web-application, hash, web-browser, javascript

Which encryption method is used for these variable names:

`var g_license_info` 
`var g_server_time_obj`

Respectfully encrypted to:

`var ago05b4e111efe149737a67a177f00ffad2`
`var agj54c415d499dcb6fb35b5fbb324ccaa6f`

Both are 35 digits but I cant find which encryption is used.

Answer (score 6):

The "encrypted" variable name is:

`"a" + first char of original var name + last char of original var name + md5sum(var name)`

so, given **g**_license_inf**o**:

```
$ echo -n g_license_info | md5sum
05b4e111efe149737a67a177f00ffad2  -
$
```

gives you "ago05b4e111efe149737a67a177f00ffad2".

Likewise, **g**_server_time_ob**j** results in "agj54c415d499dcb6fb35b5fbb324ccaa6f"

Answer (score 0):

they are MD5 with ago and agj prepended.

Run your strings through this site and check the MD5 result with your strings http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm